# SSRS: Get list of all reports and parameters in a single web service call?

Tags: c#, web-services, reporting-services

Short and sweet version: Is there a single web service method that would return the names of all available reports, and each report's parameters?

I have my web code (C#/MVC) connected to a SSRS web service, and I am able to retrieve reports through those services.

I know I can get a list of available reports like this:

```
var rService = new ReportingService2005
{
 Url = @"http://domain.com/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl",
 Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
};

var reportList = rService.ListChildren(@"/Blah", true);
```

The result of ListChildren() gives a lot of information, but it doesn't list the parameters for each report. In order to get the parameter for a report, I need to make a separate call:

```
string historyId = null;
ReportService.ParameterValue[] values = null;
ReportService.DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;

var parameters = rService.GetReportParameters(@"/Blah/" + reportName, historyId, true, values, credentials);
```

So if I want to get all available reports and their parameters, I would need to loop through the results of ListChildren, which means I would be making a web service call for each of those reports.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I ended up using the method I described above, but then caching the results on the sever for an hour. For my specific situation, I know that the reports will not change often, and if they do, it's not required that the list of reports is immediately updated on the website. Your results may vary.

Comment: What's wrong with making a call for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such a call bulitin to the webservices interface. As an alternative, you could achieve something similar by directly querying the reporting services systems tables in the ReportServer DB; but this is going to be version dependant, and MS probably will not support it.

That being said I have used these tables to create several adhoc reports in the past. and did not experience any problems YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

i used ListChildren these way.

```
ReportingService2005 rService = new ReportingService2005();
rService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

CatalogItem[] catalogItems = rService.ListChildren("/", true);
```

these will give you all reports, folders and data source from Report manager.
then filter it with your code like,

```
foreach (CatalogItem item in catalogItems.Where(m => m.Name.ToLower().Contains(model.ReportName.ToLower())))
{
  Your code;    
}
```