# SSRS 2008 Web service

Tags: ssrs-2008

I need to get all on-demand reports name from report server

[SSRS: Get list of all reports and parameters in a single web service call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169063/ssrs-get-list-of-all-reports-and-parameters-in-a-single-web-service-call)

That link specify how to do it in sql server 2005 report server.

I have sql server 2008 
i have tried http://10.230.193.131/ReportServer/ReportService2008.asmx?wsdl
but it gives 
"The path of the item 'wsdl' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath) Get Online Help"

But I am able to  see  http://10.230.193.131/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl

But I am not able to find the node where i get names of all reports

In short how can i get the name of all reports by consuming a service of  SSRS 2008

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try using the ListChildren method in the ReportService2010 web service?
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listchildren.aspx
- Your question was specific to using the SSRS web service interface, but you could also query the SSRS tables directly in sql:

  ```
  SELECT 
     [Path]        [ReportPath],
     Name          [ReportName],
     Type          [ReportType],
     [Description] [ReportDescription]
  FROM
     dbo.[Catalog]
  WHERE
     [Type] = 2   -- 1= Folder, 2= Report
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Mention like

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"/EmployeeData";
```

`@` symbol as single `/` is treated as special character.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do it in the same way as in the link you provided.

You can't access "http://10.230.193.131/ReportServer/ReportService2008.asmx?wsdl" because such thing does not exist. There are 3 endpoints for SQL Server 2008 (I'll assume you have the R2 version) and they are mentioned here:

http://www.blograndom.com/blog/2011/03/reportservice2010-asmx-is-not-the-only-end-point/

All you should do is generate ReportService2010 proxy using wsdl and proceed as in the link you provided.